# How to Make Sketch/Pages like sidebar in osx

Tags: macos, cocoa

[image]

I'm trying to make an application similar to Sketch, and I have no clue how the sidebar (the one on the right) is made, even after searching everywhere on Google. I would appreciate it if someone helped point me in the right direction.

I found something called NSPanel that seems relevant, but there are very few examples on it, and the Apple documentation is not that clear either..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no complete object for doing something like this, but here is how I would build it:

I'd start with a `NSSplitViewController` object for the pane. You can set a fixed width if you want to & the pane is easily collapsable.

Inside the split view item on the right I would put a `NSScrollView` object, depending on how much elements need to fit in.

Inside, use a `NSStackView` to store all element groups. The layout will be automatically be adjusted depending on the elements height. A plus: Single elements can be hidden (or minimized) easily.

On top of the scroll view, you can put a tab bar if you have multiple panes. Here you can, again, use an `NSStackView` to layout the buttons.

*Feel free to ask if you need help with the implementation details on these objects.*